# Калмыкский или калмыцкий?

Tags: словообразование

Здравствуйте.
Возник вопрос по поводу выбора суффикса: -ск- или -к-? Учитывая, что чередование к/ч/ц есть, прилагательное от слова "калмык" образовано с помощью суф. -к- или же с помощью суф. -ск-, т.к. основа слова "калмык" оканчивается на  -к? Если это уже обсуждалось, дайте ссылочку. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из правила насчет чередования к/ц есть исключения: узбекский, такжикский, но от слова "калмык" образуется "калмыцкий" (я на всякий случай сверился с  орфографическим словарем).

Comment: Спасибо за исключения.

Answer (score 2):

Происходит чередование К-Ц. Думаю, что правильно "калмыЦкий" Как "казак" - казаЦкий, ткач - ткацкий.

Comment: Спасибо. Хотелось бы точнее. А то получается, что оба варианта возможны. Но один явно грозит орфографической ошибкой.

Answer (score 1):

Калмыцкий. [Здесь есть это слово и правило.](http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.28)

Comment: Спасибо огромное.